# Start a main window using swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm kind of new in swift, but I'm '*stuck*' in something.

I know C, Java, C++, PHP, etc...

I'm trying to compose an multi-windowed App (Mac OS application using Cocoa), using swift. I can already do it, but my problem is when I close the *main* window. If I close my main window, when I try to add a child to it, I will get an error or the new window just does not open.

I have this:

```
class SmallWindow: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow! //Window inside the .xib file

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}
```

I already tried the above using `NSWindowController` and `NSWindow`.

```
var smallwin = SmallWindow()
smallwin.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self) 
//already tried with smallwin.window too
```

I am wondering how to programmatically start a new window. Am I missing some steps?

```
@IBOutlet var window: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet var smallwin : SmallWindow!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    smallwin = SmallWindow()
    window.addChildWindow(smallwin.window, ordered: NSWindowOrderingMode.Above)

}
```

Comment: Check the nib to make sure you didn't set this window to be released when closed.

Comment: with the 'this' you mean the main window right?

Comment: Yes, it's just an idea, but I've made this mistake and had the window go out of existence when closed. - However, I don't understand what you mean by "add a child to it"; a closed window can't have a child window.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: you are assigning `SmallWindow()` to a local variable. This means that it will go out of existence immediately. That could be a mistake! Shouldn't you be assigning it to a property?

Comment: I have it like in the edit1*

Comment: (1) If it's an outlet then the SmallWindow should be coming from the nib. If it's coming from the nib then you should not be making a new one, as you do in the code you gave in your question. (2) If the code you gave in your question is not your real code, that's bad. Always show what you are _really_ doing.

Comment: (1) That was how I was adding the child. The @IBOutlet was me trying things... I've been around this for 2 days now and still no luck. But i have a basic nib with just a window inside (2) This is my real code that i've been working on.

Comment: Why do you think you want a child window?

Comment: No, that's the way I was able to add more windows. I know probably its wrong, but I can't seem to find another way to add a window to the app any other way... AS I said, i'm new to swift (and Cocoa), and do not know many of the functions of it. That's why I opened this question. How am I able to open a new window without adding a child?

Comment: Oooh, @robmayoff cuts to the heart of the matter! :)

Comment: But @Leandroc in your edit 1 you are still making the same mistake. You presumably get the window controller as an outlet (since this is an `IBOutlet`), but then you replace it with a different one that you create in code. That's nuts.

Comment: A "child window" is an outmoded interface item, almost never used nowadays, where a secondary window is attached to another window so that it moves together with it. I haven't seen one in 10 years or more. - If you just want a window, just make a window. It doesn't need to be anything's child.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that... but it does not appear when I run the app... how do I 'draw' it to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need a **child** window.  You just need a window.

To put a new window on the screen, you need to do three things:

1. Create the window, either programmatically or by loading a nib.
2. Send an order-in message to the window.  Usually you want to send `makeKeyAndOrderFront` or `orderFront`.  See [“Opening and Closing Windows” in the *Window Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/OpeningClosingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000226-CJBCCCEF).
3. Keep a strong reference to the window.  The system doesn't necessarily keep a strong reference to an on-screen window.  If the window is deallocated, it will remove itself from the screen.

Comment: I think it is some problem with my xCode... I used the exact same code on my friends computer and it worked like magic.